# Cassandra data is not getting indexed into ElasticSearch using elassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector, elassandra

I am using elassandra-6.2.3.4. And also using cassandra-spark connector to write a spark dataframe into Casaandra.It is writing dataframe into Cassandra successfully but it is not syncing with ElasticSearch.It is not showing any data into ES.

But when I write data in Cassandra by using Insert statement then it creates index for rows in elasticsearch but in case of writing df into Cassandra, it is not creating index in ES
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance?

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: Actually we were using a field in Cassandra with frozen and map. That's why it was not getting synced to ES. But now we changed our schema and removed the frozen and declare this field as only map type.Now its working fine.
Thanks for your response.